# How to exclude child war deploy from parent pom with tomcat7 plugin?

Tags: maven, deployment, tomcat7

My parent `pom` has seven modules, five of which package `jar` and two of which package `war`. I want one of the wars to be deployed using `mvn tomcat7` but not the other.

> Parent POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

> Deployed POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
        <path>/mywebapp</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The non-deployed POM does not declare any tomcat7 maven plugin. However, when I run `mvn tomcat7:redeploy` at the parent POM level, it wants to deploy every POM that packages a war, succeeding at the deployed POM and failing at the non-deployed one:

```
[INFO] Deployed WAR artifact ......................................... SUCCESS [ 49.072 s]
[INFO] Non-deployed WAR artifact ..................................... FAILURE [  0.594 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 57.209 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-22T11:49:01-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 60M/704M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'tomcat7' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven
.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (D:\DATA\.m2), central (https://repo.maven
.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

How can I exclude the second artifact from being deployed while still keeping its WAR file rebuild in its target directory when `mvn tomcat7:redeploy` is run?